# There is a problem with Oracle to_char(Date)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle to_char(Date)  to show time， everything is ok except for one of the data. Cannot show '20' before '2019'. I don't know the reason.

[image: plsql query result]

Try to add more row data, everything works, only one piece of data has a problem.It's very strange.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(STARTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DISPLAY_STARTDATE, STARTDATE,
       to_char(STARTDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DISPLAY_CREATEDATE, CREATEDATE, ID
FROM TB_DING_MEETING
ORDER BY CREATEDATE DESC
```

I expect the output of '19/7/26 15:30:00' to be '2019-07-26 15:30', but the actual output is '0019-07-26 15:30'. Note that only one piece of data is wrong.
You can see the column startdate 19/7/26 mean July 19,Year 2019.startdate and createdate's column types is date

[image: plsql client]

Thank you so much to everyone who helped.

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: startdate and createdate column date types is date

Comment: But doesn't 19/7/26 mean July 26, year 19?

Comment: In plsql client, I can see the column startdate 19/7/26 mean July 26, year 2019.

Comment: Even for row 3? I'd guess someone has inserted year 19 for that specific row.

Comment: Your client is only showing 2-digit years, so you can't say it is 2019. Clearly the value stored in the database is actually 0019 for that `start_date`. (You know `display_createdate` is showing your `start_date` again, not `create_date`, right?)

Comment: Add `YEAR(STARTDATE)` to your SELECT and see what you get.

Comment: Your client's default date format seems to strip century from years. That can easily hide errors such as having a date in year 19 rather than 2019, which is probably the case here. If I recall correctly, Oracle allows dates down to year 0 (it doesn't really care about calendar changes).

Comment: Not sure which tool you use (displayed in these screenshots), but I would not put too much trust in the popup calendar. `to_char` can be trusted. Like others said, you have a date there that really is in 19 AD. It is strange that your first thought is "there is something wrong with `to_char`" and not "there is something wrong with the data". Which is more likely?

Comment: See what you get when you do `select startdate from tb_ding_meeting order by startdate`. Do you see anything odd in the first results?

Comment: Oh, display_createdate is showing wrong,  I want to show create_date.Maybe it's really a value insert error，Thank you all

Comment: Many Oracle clients provide a setting to choose default date format. For instance, in SQL Developer it can be found at *Tools/ Preferences/ Database/ NLS*. Mine is `DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS` (I'm in Western Europe). Perhaps your program has a similar configuration.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The Georgian Calendar, resp. ISO 8601 is a Proleptic

calendar, I. E. it applies also for times of prior it was introduced.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was actually surprised by year zero but I see [it's in fact valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero).

Comment: Somebody entered year 19, and my plsql client's default year format only have two digits and it's popup calendar still identify year 19 as year 2019 caused a misunderstanding,  thank you all.